# Is it acceptable to post an implementation of a concept in another answer with due attribution?

Tags: discussion

I originally commented on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011292/reading-numbers-from-input-haskell/28011672#28011672) with a response similar to user @phg, but then deleted it because I had skimmed through the post and wasn't sure I had got it right.

The aforementioned user then added an answer which was conceptual rather than a concrete implementation/code snippet. I added an answer, then deleted it when I realised it wasn't addressing OP's question. I then undeleted the same answer, added in the code snippet to resolve OP's issue, with comments on my changes to OP's logic, and also kept the code that was in my original post with an explanation of when that could be used. In doing so, I have already stated that my answer is basically a concrete implementation of the concepts discussed by @phg.

In this scenario, would it be considered acceptable to keep my answer, since I believe it is adding value rather than merely repeating another answer?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Absolutely. You're doing it exactly right, and it seems that at least three voters agree (your answer has four upvotes and phg's only one).

Using another post as a springboard, attributing the ideas but going into more detail while still solving the problem does nothing but make the page more useful for anyone who reads it.

Comment: This reminds me of one answer I did - with code and explanation. Someone else just verbally repeated what my code was showing and got the reputation for it. Sometimes I wonder if people do that on purpose... If you spend effort in creating an answer, imho, you should not worry too much about what someone else also did (maybe even in parallel to your working on your answer).